# jenkins Pipeline Script: How to get the return value from shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline where I am executing different scripts at different stages. However in one stage I want to get the output of the stage to a variable where I want to pass that variable as an input to next stage . Here is my code in Jenkinsfile

```
timestamps
{
  node('cf_slave')
  {
    checkout scm
    stage('Download HA image from GSA')
    {
      withCredentials(usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'ssc4icp_GSA', usernameVariable: 'GSA_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GSA_PASSWORD')
      {
        environment {
          script {
            OUTPUT = """${sh(
                            returnStdout: true,
                            script: 'bash jenkins/try_install.sh $VAR_ABC'
                         )}"""
            echo $OUTPUT
          }   
        }
      }       
    }
}
}
```

Here i am getting syntax error. I want to get the OUTPUT in OUTPUT variable and pass that to next stage. Please help me how to do that in a correct way

Comment: `sh` is a pipeline method and not to be cast a string. Try removing the `""""${...}"""` and then modifying the single quotes to double quotes in your string input to the `script` argument and it should work.

Comment: I changed the code to `OUTPUT  = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "bash jenkins/try_install.sh $VAR_ABC")` but still getting error message `Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 44: unexpected token: } @ line 44, column 5.
       }
       ^

1 error
`

Answer (score 2):

When referencing variable outside of a string you should not us a dollar sign ($). The code should be (including changes suggested by Matt):

```
timestamps
{
  node('cf_slave')
  {
    checkout scm
    stage('Download HA image from GSA')
    {
      withCredentials(usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'ssc4icp_GSA', usernameVariable: 'GSA_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GSA_PASSWORD'))
      {
        environment {
          script {
            OUTPUT = sh returnStdout: true,
                     script: "bash jenkins/try_install.sh $VAR_ABC"
            echo OUTPUT
          }   
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as above with this code as well

Comment: I spotted another error in the code, there was a closing parenthesis missing on line 8 (withCredentials....). So try the the corrected code above.